# Oracle JDK-1.8 installation issue on Ubuntu-20.04-LTS

Tags: apt, java, ppa, docker, oracle

With below Dockerfile trying to install Oracle JDK-1.8. But it fails during docker build.

```py
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install Oracle JDK 1.8
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get -y update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer && \
    java -version
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Docker build errors,

```py
Debian installation instructions:
- Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && apt-get -y update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

As per this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) Noticed that PPA support is available till Ubuntu-16.10.

> Our PPA supports Ubuntu 16.10, 16.04, 15.10, 14.04 and 12.04 as well
> as Linux Mint 18, 17.x and 13. Add the PPA and install Oracle Java 8
> (the package provides both JDK8 and JRE8) using the following
> commands:

Is there any workaround to install oracle JDK-1.8 on Ubuntu-20.04-LTS docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you blindly adding some PPA to your Dockerfile. This [Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) does not provide packages for 20.04 LTS (*focal*) - see http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/ , also it is now marked as discontinued by its owners.

You have to replace this PPA by some other, for example [this  “Hellenic Schools Technical Support Team” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ets.sch.gr/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal) provides needed [package for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/%7Ets.sch.gr/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=oracle-java8-installer&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal) .

So you have to put the following line into Dockerfile:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ts.sch.gr/ppa
```